# Yellow sticky note in the wind

Tags: animation, physics

I would like to make an animation of some [yellow sticky notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-it_note) (on a table) slightly moving in the wind. I already tried the cloth and soft body physics, but neither provide me the desired affect.

An attached to a table sticky note is elastic in the up/down movement but is rather hard in left/right movements. Also an attached sticker can hardly be folded by the wind or become wrinkles.

Could you please point me to the right direction of animating this?

In particular:

- Which physic body to use (soft, cloth, any other)
- What kind of wind or other force field to use (strong/light)
- Should the sticker be a simple plane a very thin mash with the volume >0

Comment: sorry can't understand what is an "attached to a table sticker" and how it should behave... any reference?

Comment: You just put a small yellow sticker on the table and it sticks with its top sticky part. The remaining part elevates slightly above the table. Did you get the idea?

Comment: I think he is describing a Postit Note.

Comment: A [post it note](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-it_note)?  can you elaborate on result you gained from soft body / cloth and what was wrong with them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Final:

[image: postit]

### Scene setup:

[image: scene]

**Plane (table).**

This is just simple **Plane** with added **Collision** (default setup). It should be a little bit below sticky note.

**Sticky note.**

Another **Plane**, **Subdivided** with **Weight Paint** and **Cloth physics**.

- **Weight Paint** - Red color is 'sticky' part, green is still little stiff and blue for full influence. You can paint it differently if you want.
- **Cloth physics** - main goal here was to make it light and stiff.

  [image: cloth]

  - **Quality** - 20, for better overall animation and smoothness,
  - **Mass** - 0.1, Wind and Gravity influence,
  - **Structural, Bending, Spring** - 400, 500, 50, all for getting rid of small wrinkles,
  - **Air** - 4, it will slightly increase air resistance and smooth wind influence,
  - **Pinning** - Group, most important thing here, this one will take **Weight Paint** as stiffness map,
  - **Cloth Collision > Quality** - 4, for better collision with table.
- **Force Field > Turbulence** - this one could be Wind or probably something else. Adjust **Strength**, **Noise** as you like, but keep **Size** at 10. You can animate position of it and also Strength and Noise. Additionally you can add more of them with different settings.

  [image: force]

Answer (score 3):

I would try to use a setup like this: I'm not so satisfied with the "sticker" deform but... at least I hope it will give you some inspiration...

I created an initally deformed "sticker" (I used a curve deform to set the shape slightly lifted)

[image]

Then I've set a wind force field acting on the "cloth sticker", using a sticky vertex group to make that part to "stick" to the base.

Other key settings here are a leser "velocity" and gravity deactivation...

[image]

here is my test file
[image]

btw, there's a hidden copy of the sticker with default cloth settings, for comparison

edit: due to animated gif begging :D  I add here an animated comparison although the nearest "postit" has a really subtle movement, respect to the other (the hidden one I was referring above) that has default cloth settings... for this reason I added the .blend where it is easier to see the movement, and tinker with settings...

[image]

Comment: ... begs for an animated gif 8^)

Comment: @batFINGER stop begging! I've added it :D

Comment: stiffer springs? oh and [this is begging](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91524/python-generated-orco-texture-coordinate-to-2d-image#comment161496_91524)