# Paper on wall pulling with wind

Tags: soft-body, force-fields

I want to create a scene with a piece of paper stuck on a wall fluttering in the wind for a while, before being torn off and blown away. I attempted this with a soft body subdivided plane and wind force field, but wasn't able to get the desired fluttering effect. I want it to appear as if there is a strong wind.

How could I do this?

Comment: Maybe this will help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/91480/yellow-sticky-note-in-the-wind